# ObjC How to dispose of a Singleton Object when the app is NOT quitting

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

My (iOS7 / ARC) app has the concept of "log in" where a user connects to a remote server.  For the duration of the users logged-in session, I have some singleton objects to handle low level aspects (sockets, process incoming messages, etc).  When the user logs out, I would like to dispose of these singletons and then recreate them when the user logs back in (assumed is the app is not dying off or being quit).

The singleton is created so:

```
static MYChatMessageManager *messageManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;

+(MYChatMessageManager *) messageManager
{
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       messageManager = [[self alloc] init];
       // Do any other initialisation stuff here
       });
   return messageManager;
}
```

and I defined a class method which I thought would accomplish the task

```
+(void) shutdown
{
    onceToken = 0;
    messageManager = nil;
}
```

When I call this, I would expect that the `-dealloc` method of the singleton instance to be called since ARC should see no one has reference to it.  However, `-dealloc` is not being called and in the debugger, after the `+shutdown` is called, I stop the app (`shutdown` has run and several seconds late I just stop the app) and examine the object at the memory location I have for messageManager (gotten from lldb earlier, not in code) and it still has a `retainCount` of 1.  I can identify no place in my app that any variable or object pointer is assigned this object which would increment the retain count through ARC.

I am not sure what I can do to make this singleton go away.

Comment: *I would like to dispose of these singletons and then recreate them when the user logs back in* That sounds like a shared object rather than a singleton.

Comment: Never mind -- there was a sneaky reference to the singleton in a block handler on an event handler that had been registered elsewhere.  My bad.  Did not see it the first time I went through all the code to find references.

Comment: My best guess is somewhere else in your program you have another reference to `messageManager`  BTW, you can't reset `dispatch_once_t` tokens reliably, so you'll need to adopt another approach, @synchronized or a simple test, depending on whether or not you need thread safety.

Comment: @caleb    What is the difference really between a shared object and a singleton?  The singleton can only exist as a single object and is shared amongst all users.

Comment: @chadbag I'd say the difference is lifecycle.  A singleton has a lifecycle that matches that of the program.  A shared object has a controllable lifecycle.

Comment: @David  I can go back to the @ynchronized classic locking pattern, however, in reading the various explanations of why resetting `dispatch_once_t` tokens is not always reliable, it looks to do with memory read/write reorderings at the HW level and given the time scale where I do this, that should be irrelevant.  However, there is no performance issue and any of the classic methods will work for me.  Thanks for the comments -- I learned some stuff.

Comment: @chadbag my recollection of the problems has to do with write barriers (low level exceptions on writes to specific memory address/ranges) and there being no way to reset the barriers.  I thought I had seen it in the Apple reference pages as well, but I'm not finding it now.

Comment: @David  Yes, there are various explanations on SO that talk about the write barriers.  These are needed due to the HW reordering of reads and writes according to the SO articles I read, as far as I understood them, so the need with my orders of magnitude greater time differentials would not be there.  The SO articles were talking about using it at an object level and not class level where you could be creating and destroying objects frequently and at close time intervals (based on what I read and understood).

Comment: All I know is that threading issues are such a pain in the ass to uncover it's worth avoiding the possibility :)

Comment: @david  amen to that!  Thanks for your insights. I learned from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Allocations Instrument, turn on reference event tracking, and then see what is holding the final reference(s).

Which you have done, more or less (found the last reference at least).

However, this is bad design and the code is buggy.   First, as noted in comments, a `dispatch_once_t` cannot be reset.

Secondly, and the bigger issue, you should *never destroy a shared instance* and, by implication, there should be no critical logic in the class's `-dealloc` method (which, btw, is more of a general rule than one specific to shared instance classes).

By the definition of "shared instance", that object should stick around forever.   If it needs to transition between "active" and "shutdown" states, then add that logic in a fashion that does not connect it to the object's lifespan.

Comment: Hi Bill.  There is no logic in dealloc.  I just want to get rid of the memory and resource usage when a user is not logged in.  Nothing prevents having a shutdown method but letting the object go away is/would be easier since rebuilding it and restarting it are basically the same.  Thanks.

Comment: @chadbag It isn't basically the same, though.  In one case, you no longer have a singleton and must have the logic throughout your codebase to deal with a manager that may go away entirely.  In the other case, you have a singleton that contains the logic to tear itself down to basically no resource usage.   That's a huge difference.

Comment: Not really.   At least in my case, if the singleton is not there any more, it is rebuilt, the same as when someone tries to use it the first time when a program first starts execution.  Using an older `@synchronized` check for creation instead of `dispatch_once`

Answer (score 0):

There was a sneaky block handler based reference to the object that a third review of the code uncovered.  Sorry for the false alarm.